# Git and .ssh issue connecting to remote repository

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to connect to the college remote repository with Git. I have placed a private key generated in college in my .ssh folder under the home directory. However, when I try to connect to the college server, I am being asked for a password. Does anyone know the reason for this? Does the private key have any naming restrictions? When asked for the password do I have to point to the RSA? Any advice is very welcome

thanks

Comment: Is the remote repository public or have you (or someone) uploaded your ssh keys to it?

Comment: No it is private but the keys have been created successfully. That is I have been able to access the repository from my college machine

Answer (score 0):

The public key should be named authorized_keys and placed in your /home/username/.ssh directory.

It also needs read only file permissions, something like:

```
chmod 400 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

should do it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be read-only, but it should be accessible only by the user. So 600 will suffice just as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. I am just wondering about the config. As the username and email information is different on my own machine to the one in college, do I need to specify this info somewhere to allow the college server to id me?

Comment: I just reread the question, its the public key that should be placed on the remote system and private key at home with you.  You can't generate a new private key at home,  you need the same private key they you created at college